# use "wine" with php's shell_exec

Tags: php, debian, exec, shell-exec, wine

I am currently trying to use a "wine" command from my PHP-Script.

If i execute this:

```
$shell = shell_exec("/usr/bin/wine --version");
```

All is working fine and WINE version is displayed in $shell.

**But, if i try to make it like this:**

```
$run = shell_exec("/usr/bin/wine ".$workdir."/bin/tool.exe -m ".$workdir."/bin/std.maps -a ".$workdir."/bin/alias.file -n ".$workdir."/files/".$project_name."/upload/dump.bin -o ".$workdir."/files/".$project_name."/maps/definitions.list");
```

Which results in:

```
$run = shell_exec("/usr/bin/wine /var/www/html/bin/tool.exe -m /var/www/html/bin/std.maps -a /var/www/html/bin/alias.file -n /var/www/html/files/1-59374-94700/upload/dump.bin -o /var/www/html/files/1-59374-94700/maps/definitions.list 2>&1");
```

I get the following output:

> wine: chdir to /.wine  : No such file or directory

What i am doing wrong? If i enter the command above directly to the shell, all is working fine. If i do it without /usr/bin/ in front of wine, the output's are the same.

Br, Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't try it myself but I think it is because wine is run as different user with different environment settings. Try create `.wine` directory inside `/var/www` and make `www-data` user as owner of this directory and make `/var/www/.wine` HOME directory.

```
$run = shell_exec("HOME=/var/www/.wine /usr/bin/wine ".$workdir."/bin/tool.exe -m ".$workdir."/bin/std.maps -a ".$workdir."/bin/alias.file -n ".$workdir."/files/".$project_name."/upload/dump.bin -o ".$workdir."/files/".$project_name."/maps/definitions.list");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be working now. 
But, the script-runtime is very long. I tried with sudo, and there the runtime was about ~ 0.5 sek, now with your solution it runs about 4 seconds, and i get the X-Server warning's. (It's a cmd line tool so i need no graphic-output. 

Do you know, how to get this to work? I dont want to use sudo. Br